# while loop for scanning user input table into array

Tags: c

I am a super unintuitive beginner programming student working on a homework assignment. The program is to take an input table of hockey teams and game stats, calculate "points", and then output the table organized in a different way, with additional columns for points and games played.

So far, I haven't made it past scanning the input. With my while loop, I'm trying to first determine if the string is a conference name or a team name and then scan and store the subsequent table values accordingly. I'm just trying to print the same table back out at this point, but when i copy/paste the input input table which was given, I get no output, and when I manually type it in, it comes out suuper weird.

The input table looks something like this:

Conference1_Name    3               (teams in conference)

Team_1_Name 31 15 2 2 (wins, losses, ot losses, shootout losses)

Team_2_Name 24 21 1 0

Team_3_Name 27 19 0 2

Conference2_Name    4

Team_4_Name 30 15 1 1

...

aaand this is my code so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    int n=0, N=25, nE=0, nW=0, i, w[n], l[n], otl[n], sol[n], gp[n], pts[n];
    char input[30], team[n][30];

    printf("Enter conference data\n");
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

    while(n<=N){
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (0==strcmp(input, "Eastern_Conference")) {
            scanf("%d", &nE);
            continue; //does not count eastern conference as a team, but stores number of teams, and does not increment n
        }

        if (0==strcmp(input, "Western_Conference")) {
            scanf("%d", &nW);
            continue; //does not count western conference as a team, but stores number of teams, and does not increment n
        }

        if (0==strcmp(input, "EOD")) break; 

    //originally i had a statement like: if (nE>0 && nW>0){N=nE+nW;) so that the loop condition n<N will break the loop on it's own but thought maybe EOD would simplify it and fix my problem//


        strcpy(team[n], input);
        scanf("%d%d%d%d", &w[n], &l[n], &otl[n], &sol[n]);

        gp[n]=w[n]+l[n];
        pts[n]=(2*w[n])+otl[n]+sol[n];

        n++;

    }   //so we have input the data and calculated points

    printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", "WHL", "GP", "W", "L", "OTL", "SL", "PTS");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", team[i], gp[i], w[i], l[i], otl[i], sol[i], pts[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your first two lines in `main` uses `n` as the size for many array variables. But `n` is 0 at that point. So you have all 0 sized arrays. Maybe you meant to use `N` instead? This also illustrates why it is bad practice to use variable names that are so similar.

Comment: I know that is what you intended `n` to do. The intention is fine. It's just that you are also using `n` incorrectly to intialise your array sizes. For example `w[n]` makes an aray with 0 elements instead of 25. Change that to `w[N]`. Same for the other array variables. Make sense?

Comment: Also, `while(n<=N)` is wrong. That will allow `n` to be `25`. But 25 is not a valid array index and using it will overflow the arrays. The valid array indices are 0 to 24. Needs to be `while(n<N)`. Probably other errors but I haven't looked through all the code. fix those first and re-test.